# Mysql Insert new row on 2 primary key

Tags: mysql, logic, smarty, primary-key, innodb

I've googled this question but didn't found anything. The problem is so:
I have such table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Hourly` (
  `gmt` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `city` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `temp` float NOT NULL,
  `temp_min` float NOT NULL,
  `temp_max` float NOT NULL,
  `pressure` float NOT NULL,
  `humidity` int(11) NOT NUL`enter code here`L,
  `temp_kf` float NOT NULL,
  `weather` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `icon` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `clouds` float NOT NULL,
  `wind_speed` float NOT NULL,
  `wind_deg` float NOT NULL,
  `rain_3h` float NOT NULL,
  `snow_3h` float NOT NULL,
  `sys_pod` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `received` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`gmt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The problem is I want to insert new row when both `gmt` and `city` doesn't exist, **not one of them**.
For example, my table already filled by

```
INSERT INTO `Hourly` (`gmt`, `city`, ...) VALUES
(1373446800, 1, ...)
```

And i want to insert new row

```
INSERT INTO `Hourly` (`gmt`, `city`, ...) VALUES
(1373446800, 2, ...)
```

Otherwise, it should be updated

So, i hope, i described my problem and some "smartmen" would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO Hourly (gmt, city) VALUES
    (?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    city = ?
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is not solution for my problem. 1)`gmt` is not necessarily to be primary.2)I want to update if both city and gmt are doesn't exist; else {insert new row}

Comment: @УрматЖеналиев what do you mean `gmt` is not necessarily primary?  In the table you posted you have `PRIMARY KEY (\`gmt\`)`

Comment: Sorry, for my english. gmt must be primary

Comment: @УрматЖеналиев use a different primary key